# Prevent form submission and get all the elements with a specific class in jquery

Tags: jquery, foreach, form-submit, preventdefault

I have a form something like below

```
<html>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         // find all the hidden input elements with error_check class
         var error_elements = $('.error_check')

         // Loop through each element find if the value equals 'california'
             error_elements.each(function(){
                      if (element.value == 'california')
                             // prevent for submission and display alert
                             alert("cannot submit tax for this state")
                      else 
                          // submit form

               });
     )};
  </script> 
  <body>
    <form action="{% url 'collect_salextax' %}" method="POST" id="states_form"  class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
         {% for state in states %} 
           <p>
                <input id="error_{{state.0}}" type="hidden" name="{{state.0}} value="{{state.name}}" class="error_check"/>
                <input id="{{state.0}}" type="text" name="{{state.0}}" class="value_check"/>
           </p>
         {% endfor %} 
      </div>
      <div class="span11 pagination-centered marg_tp38">
           <input name="" type="submit" class="btn btn-large big_btn " value="Submit">
      </div>                          
    </form>
  <body>
</html>
```

So from the above as u can see i am generating the fields in a paragraph using a loop, and the value of hidden field will be state name from the `array/list`

So when i click on the submit button, its successfully going to form action attribute and returning the result

So can anyone please let me know how to do this very clearly in jquery ?

But what i am trying is, when a user clicks on `submit` button

1. I need to get all the `hidden input elements` with class `error_check`
2. Loop through the elements and find the value of each element, if the element value 
   name is equal to `"California"`, then display an alert like "You cannot submit tax 
   for california"
3. Else submit the form to action attribute

Comment: suggesting to use window.onload instead of $(document).ready

Comment: wrap this validation `if (element.value == 'california')` in submit button click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
$("#states_form").submit(function(event) {
    $(".error_check").each(function(idx, obj) {
        if ($(obj).val() == 'california') {
            alert("cannot submit tax for this state");
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // submit form
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its telling me Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'

Comment: check the modified now

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a submit even handler to your form. If something doesn't validate add a event.preventDefault() to make sure the form does not submit.

```
van $form = $('#myForm');
$form.on('submit', function () {
    // handle submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    var allInputs = $('.error_check');
    for(var i=0; i<allInputs.length; i++) {
        if(allInputs[i].value == "California") {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Its telling me Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val' in the console

Comment: oh sorry my mistake replace if condition with this if(allInputs[i].value == "California")